# Firebase user.linkWithCredential is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've followed this [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login#expandable-1) on how to link existing credentials with the new credentials from Facebook and everything is working as expected, except for the last part which is linking the user with the new credentials, I keep getting "user.linkWithCredential is not a function" error.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).on('click', "#btn-login-fb", function (event) {
    //A bunch of code here where I do the login process
    }).catch(function (error) {  
        //Here is where I need to handle the error and link accounts          
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        // The email of the user's account used.
        var email = error.email;
        // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
        var credential = error.credential;

        //
        //   LINKING FACEBOOK WITH EXISTING EMAIL/PASSWORD USER
        //
        if (error.code === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential') {
            // Step 2.
            // User's email already exists.
            // The pending Facebook credential.
            var pendingCred = error.credential;
            // The provider account's email address.
            var email = error.email;
            // Get sign-in methods for this email.
            firebase.auth().fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email).then(function (methods) {
                // Step 3.
                // If the user has several sign-in methods,
                // the first method in the list will be the "recommended" method to use.
                if (methods[0] === 'password') {
                    // Asks the user their password.
                    // In real scenario, you should handle this asynchronously.
                    //Abrir modal
                    document.getElementById("btnPwModal").click();
                    $(document).on('click', "#btnConfirmPw", function (event) {
                        document.getElementById("btnFecharModal").click();
                        var password = $("#inputPassword").val();
                        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function (user) {
                            // Step 4a.
                            user.linkWithCredential(pendingCred).then(function () {
                                alert("linko");
                                // Facebook account successfully linked to the existing Firebase user.
                            });;
                        });

                    })
                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Any ideas on why everything else is working but linkWithCredential is not? Thanks.

Comment: Use `console.log(..)` to debug your code; make sure the order in which things happen is as expected (assigning event listeners in the middle of branching auth flow seems weird), and make sure variables contain what you expect

Comment: I couldn't figure out another way of grabbing the password in the modal which the user type his password so I did the listener workaround, also, it seems that my user object after the signInWithEmailAndPassword is null or something because every property is undefined for user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you get after calling [`signInWithEmailAndPassword`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithemailandpassword) is a `UserCredential` object, not a `User` object. To get from `UserCredential` to ``, you call `user` on it.

So:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function (cred) {
  cred.user.linkWithCredential(pendingCred)...
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Thanks for providing the backlink! You're not the first one to have this problem, and with the link we finally know where the confusion comes from. We'll get it fixed soon too, so that hopefully you're the last one to get this mistake from our docs.